# Obtain result of GET request in javascript (and Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

I am trying to get a rudimentary GET request from a Node.js server when I click on a button.

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(`Service started on port 8080.`);
});

app.get('/clicks', (req, res) => {
  res.send("foobarbaz");
})
```

`client.js`

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", showResult);
function showResult(){
  fetch('/clicks', {method: 'GET'})
    .then(function(response){
      if(response.ok){
        return response;
      }
      throw new Error('GET failed.');
    })
    .then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

However, the console log shows:

```json
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8080/clicks", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:8080/clicks"
__proto__: Response
```

How can I get my "foobarbaz"?

If I go to `localhost:8080/clicks` the text shows up there.

Additionally, the `response` already seems to be a javascript object -- `response.json()` doesn't work.

Comment: Your server code doesn't respond with JSON, so that's why `response.json()` doesn't work. You need to set the Content-Type header when responding to the request. I suggest looking at some tutorials for how to configure express to respond with JSON. The [documentation talks about this in the Guide section](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#response-methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `send()` parameter should be a JSON. Change `server.js` to

```
app.get('/clicks', (req, res) => {
  res.send({result:"foobarbaz"});
})
```

Now you will receive a JSON as the response in `client.js` and the result can be consumed as

```
function showResult() {
    fetch('/clicks', { method: 'GET' })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('GET failed.');
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```